# "all over" vs. "all across"

Tags: word-usage

Consider these two sentences.

> people use smart phones all **over** the
>   world
>
> people use smart phones all **across** the
>   world

per [Oxford Dictionary](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/all), "all over" means "everywhere".

per Cambridge Dictionary, "across" means

> in every part of a particular place or country

And then, "all across the world" means "everywhere in the world". Obviously both of them mean the same.

However, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%20over%20the%20world%2Call%20across%20the%20world&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Call%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAll%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Call%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAll%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Call%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAll%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Call%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAll%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0) implies that the former is much more commonly used than the latter.

[image]

So, is it both grammatical and idiomatic to say "all across the world"?

---

update: thanks to @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica reminder, here is [another one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%20*%20the%20world%2Call%20across%20the%20world&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Call%20%2A%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20that%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20around%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20round%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20about%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20through%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20which%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20to%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Call%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAll%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Call%20*%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20over%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20that%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20around%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20in%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20of%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20round%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20about%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20through%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20which%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20to%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Call%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ball%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAll%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Comment: The second most common preposition here is actually [*all **around** the world*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+around+the+world%2Call+across+the+world&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20around%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20across%20the%20world%3B%2Cc0). And if you do a "wild card" search for all common alternatives on NGrams (as per my link), you'll find that ***across*** isn't even in the top ten. But they're all "grammatical", and effectively mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. I've updated my OP. It is true that "*across*" is less common. However, it is indeed in the top 10, and gets a higher points than some others.